# Java - InheritableThreadLocal leaking data across threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jetty, threadpool

**Scenario:**

I am running a Java Web application served by Jetty. I am using InheritableThreadLocal to store some data when an API is invoked and later this data is accessed when the API invokes further operations (in the same thread). The way I am storing this data is:

**Code:**

```
public class RequestDataHolder {

    protected static final InheritableThreadLocal<RequestData> reqData = new InheritableThreadLocal<RequestData>();

    public static void setRequestData(RequestData request) {
        reqData.set(request);
    }

    public static void removeRequestData() {
        reqData.remove();
    }

    public static RequestData getRequestData() {
        return (RequestData) reqData.get();
    }

}

public class RequestData {
   private String requestId;
   private String apiStartTime;

   // getters and setters
}
```

**Questions:**

1. When two API calls happen in parallel, I am seeing that sometimes Thread-1 is seeing the RequestData object what Thread-2 had set. Is there a possibility of data leak here?
2. Am I using the static methods correctly to set and get the InheritableThreadLocal?

**EDIT**

I am seeing a behavior:

1. Thread-1 sets RequestData in ITL and proceeds.
2. Thread-2 sets RequestData in ITL and proceeds.
3. Thread-1 performs a call to database.
4. Thread-2 is proceeding and modifying RequestData.
5. Thread-1 wakes up and searches for RequestData but finds the RequestData that was set was Thread-2.

Could there be something, possibly going on with the way the threads are managed in Jetty when a thread performs an I/O? Is there a possibility of a parent-child thread here due to thread-reuse?

Comment: re 1: not unless Thread-1 is spawned by Thread-2 or the code is actually running on the same thread; re 2: looks alright to me, although your cast in `getRequestData` is redundant

Comment: Using `ThreadLocal` in a web application is always prone to leaking; you have to be extremely careful with clearing out the saved data as these servers all pool threads. It is unlikely that those two threads will share `InheritableThreadLocal` state as they should be siblings; but without looking at Jetty's innards - who knows...

Comment: What is the point of a wrapper around `InheritableThreadLocal` that does not add anything to the existing API?  Why can't you use the `InheritableThreadLocal` directly and dispense with `RequestDataHolder`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't get what you mean by *leak*. `ThreadLocal` is supposed to guarantee that each thread will get a separate copy of the object, so how could such a *leak* happen ?

Comment: @Dici: there could be a leak if he naively expects his application logic per session to be tied to distinct threads in Jetty's thread pool

Comment: @Dici threads are reused. If you don't properly clear out state then you likely get a thread back at some point with some else's data.

Comment: This design seems both wrong and unnecessary.  The server thread per request and session ought to handle what you want to do.  Better yet, it'll do it correctly.

Comment: Ok, I see what you meant. Thanks Boris, oldrinb

Comment: @JimGarrison I disagree; this sort of encapsulation is an excellent idea. What if at some later point the OP adopts, for example, Spring - which provides its own per-request storage? I would argue that the way in which data is stored is exactly not the concern of any other class.

Comment: @OP - Why don't you use [`ServletRequest.setAttribute`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) rather than external storage?

Comment: @BoristheSpider - sure I can give that a shot. I just wanted to understand what's going on with the InheritedThreadLocals. Actually the weird part is that when Thread-1 is running and processing, all of a sudden when the code does a getRequestData, it sees the Request data of Thread-2 which just set it a few milliseconds ago. Is it possible that my setters and getters in the RequestDataHolder are prone to dirty writes and reads due to they being static ? Do I need to synchronize them on a monitor ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out the issue.

**Reasoning:**

The issue happened because even though Java's InheritableThreadLocal guarantees that two threads would not see each other's, but what *you* put in this variable is not *guaranteed* to be protected from being visible across the threads.

**Example:**

For example, the object "RequestData" lives on a heap. Consider this sequence of events now:

1. Thread-1 invokes a set on ITL and sets RequestData object
2. Thread-2 is a child thread spawned from Thread-1. Due to the nature
   of ITL, Thread-2 gets the ITL *transferred* over.
3. Thread-2 does a get on the ITL to retrieve RequestData. Now, this
   object would have the SAME HASH CODE as that object which was set in
   Step 1.
4. Thus, if you modify anything in Thread-2, you will end up updating
   the reference which will be visible in Thread-1 as well.

**Sample Code to prove the reasoning:**

```
    public class Test implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            RequestData requestData = new RequestData();
            System.out.println("Thread ID: Setting requestData with hash code:" + requestData.hashCode());
            RequestDataHolder.setRequestData(requestData);
            Thread child = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RequestData requestData = RequestDataHolder.getRequestData();
                    System.out.println("Thread ID: Retrieved requestData with hash code:" + requestData.hashCode());
                }
            });
            child.start();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(new Test());
            thread.start();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What's relevant in the Jetty example is that Jetty spawns new worker threads *from the previous worker threads*. So if Thread-1 spawns Thread-2, after the `InheritedThreadLocal` is initialized, from that point onwards both threads have the same value for reqData. It seems like `InheritedThreadLocal` is not safe to use in combination with Jetty.

Also, since `RequestDataHolder.reqData` is `static final`, if this class is initialized very early on in the main thread, due to the nature of `InheritedThreadLocal`, this reference will be copied to *all* child threads.